# are javascript functions when used in a callback created on each invocation?

Tags: javascript, optimization, garbage-collection

In search of minimizing GC'ing in Javascript, I'm trying to gain some by reusing functions (instead of creating them over and over again).

Which led me to the question that I can't seem to find a definitive answer to: are functions when used in a callback created on each invocation (and thus pile-up for garbage collection) or are they created once and used over and over again?

For example:

`const bigArrayClone _.map(bigArray, function(el){return el;});`

Will the above create the function `function(el){return el;}` for each and every element of `bigArray` or is it reused?

Comment: A simple look at source would have answered this yourself. There is only one instance of the function object that gets called numerous times https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/map.js

Comment: It's created as often as `_.map` is called